# How to tell which end is faulty on RJ-45 cable?

Tags: networking, rj-45

While making my own cat6 cables, I notice that every now and then, even though I push the cables all the way to the end that it will allow, my tester states FAIL and it shows certain wires blinking (like 1 and 8). How do I know which end is at fault and causing the fail (besides hoping I redo the correct side and, most of the time, having to redo the other side as well)? For reference, my tester is a Monoprice MCT-2690PRO.

Comment: Aren't the plugs made of see-thru plastic? At least with a magnifier you should see it. Can you take pictures of the plugs of a faulty cable and show them here?

Comment: Unfortunately I already redid the cable.

Comment: it might also be faulty in the middle, in theory

Comment: I'm going to rule that out as all the faulty cables I have are fixed after redoing the ends. Thumbs up though.

Comment: You can't tell which end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if you use the length option on the tester that anything with 0 in length could signal a possible wiring error. The only exception to this that I've found is if my wire is 2-3ft or less in length.

Comment: What's the length option?

Comment: One of the buttons/features that measures the length of the cord. I never use it because it is always inaccurate and each pair is different (sometimes by a foot).